# analytic function $f$ defined in open unit disk for which $f(1/n)$ is $2^n$

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I show that there does not exists an analytic function
$f$
defined in open unit disk for which
$f(1/n)$ is $2^n$
.

Answer (score 2):

Because an analytic function on an open disk is continuous on a closed disk with radius $\frac12$, thus it is bounded on this disk. Your function is not.

Answer (score 2):

There can't even be a *continuous* function like that, for if such an $f$ existed, then $f(0) = \lim_n f(1/n) = \lim_n 2^n = +\infty$...